# Вывод найденных файлов. Find, xargs и логи

Tags: bash, скрипт

есть bash скрипт который ищет файлы, сортирует и удаляет

```
find $DIR -name "*.*" -and -type f | sort -r | tail -n1 | xargs -i rm -rf '{}'
```

как сделать так чтобы удаленные файлы записывались в файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find $DIR -name "*.*" -and -type f | sort -r | tail -n1 | tee -a $FILENAME | xargs -i rm -rf '{}'
```